# lp is not printing whole page - instead prints shifted page

Tags: linux, printing, opensuse, cups

I am trying to print pdf files by

```
lp file.pdf
```

but for some reason whole page is shifted up (cutting top of the page)

my printer is HP OfficeJet 6500A Plus and cups version:

```
$ cups-config --version
2.1.3
```

any idea how to print not shifted page?

Comment: What happens if you open the pdf and then print?

Comment: it prints normally, but when I have 20 pdfs I would like to use lp and not open these in okular (I have opensuse tumbleweed if this would help)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved for me, then specifying the media explicitly:

```
lp -o media=A4 file.pdf
```